# Is there any way my child component does not initialize when I load the parent in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I'm having a problem when I enter the form that would be the parent component that automatically loads the methods that the child component has on the OnInit, this adds a bit more load to my parent component

Is there any way that my child component starts when I click a button or otherwise?

Inside my father's html I have the son in this way

```
<app-solicitud-servicios #solicitud1></app-solicitud-servicios>
```

Comment: use `*ngIf` to conditionally show/hide child

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Can not read property 'openApplication' of undefined This is the error that appears to me, This method is in the son component that is executed when I touch a button on the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *ngIf to only show it when some criteria is met. That could be after clicking a button, or whatever you want.

```
<app-solicitud-servicios *ngIf="buttonWasClicked" #solicitud1></app-solicitud-servicios>
```

It won't call OnInit in the child until the *ngIf condition is true.

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Can not read property 'openApplication' of undefined This is the error that appears to me, This method is in the son component that is executed when I touch a button on the parent

Comment: if you has *ngIf, you can not access to #solicitud1 until the condition becomes true. It's the reason to the error, try move the code when it's sure that the condition is true